# SQL Error 3780 when using foreign key as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the following order trying to use a table's primary key as another table's primary key:

*ERROR 3780 (HY000): Referencing column 'optimization_id' and referenced column 'optimization_id' in foreign key constraint 'optimization.main - optimization.status' are incompatible.*

I'm using the primary key of `OPTIMIZATION.main` as the primary key of `OPTIMIZATION.status` as well since it's a one-to-one relationship and I thought this would be easier/simpler than just adding an `id` in every table as the primary key. These are the only tables where I'm doing this, the other ones I'm not using the foreign key as the primary key as well. However, it seemed easier/simpler to do this for the few important tables I'm using to organize the data together.

My questions therefore are:

1. Why am I getting error 3780 using the provided code?
2. If this isn't best practice, what would be another way of doing this?
3. Is it even possible to use a *different* table's primary key (like
   `main`) as the primary key for another table (like `status`)?

In [this DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=702c4c1a2fab51075e8a65ec1ed1dd0d) is the code I'm using, generated by SqlDBM, to create these two tables.

Here is the visualization of the two tables (one visualized relationship isn't applicable in this case) through the SqlDBM software.

[image: Visualization of tables]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `main` table the id is an `int unsigned` in the `status` table it is only `int` which are incompatible. change both to `unsigned int` or only `int`

```
CREATE TABLE `OPTIMIZATION`.`main`
(
 `optimization_id`       int unsigned NOT NULL ,
 `optimization_name`     varchar(250) NOT NULL ,
 `optimization_category` varchar(200) NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`optimization_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `OPTIMIZATION`.`status`
(
 `current_status`  varchar(25) NULL ,
 `discovery_date`  datetime NULL ,
 `processed_date`  datetime NULL ,
 `processed_by`    varchar(100) NULL ,
 `optimization_id` int unsigned NOT NULL ,

PRIMARY KEY (`optimization_id`),
KEY `fkIdx_409` (`optimization_id`),
CONSTRAINT `optimization.main - optimization.status` FOREIGN KEY `fkIdx_409` (`optimization_id`) REFERENCES `OPTIMIZATION`.`main` (`optimization_id`)
);
```

Comment: Oh wow, glad the answer was so easy! It already works. Just a quick additional question: is this (using a foreign key as the primary key) a good setup in the sense that it's usable, or is this definitely not best practice / not recommended due to whatever reason?

Comment: it is fine to use a PK as FK.